# PHP DOM parsing HTML table

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a HTML table in a page.

However, it is not the only TABLE in the page, and I am only interested in parsing the 2nd `<table>` instnace in the HTML page.

How do I specify to parse only the 2nd TABLE instance in the HTML page?

```
//the table by its tag name  
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DOMNodelist->item() (item() expects as argument the index, it's zero-based so 1 will return the 2nd table )

```
 $table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(1);
```